# PayPal Mobile Payments Library - Libraries do not communicate with the app

Tags: ios, xcode, paypal

I am developing an application using the PayPal API. It is a simple application with one button that executes a simple payment. I have a sandbox account and I can see there that the payment has been carried out correctly.

But the problem is that within the application, I am not able to receive any response. Methods like `paymentSuccessWithKey:`, `paymentFailedWithCorrelationID:`, `paymentCanceled:` or `paymentLibraryExit:` are not executed in the code.

Comment: Have you added `PayPalPaymentDelegate` to the relevant `.h` file in your code?

Comment: Yes, but I have solved the issue. I was using a UIButton made in the Interface Builder and the app only works if you use a PayPal button like: [self addLabelWithText:@"Simple Payment" andButtonWithType:BUTTON_294x43 withAction:@selector(pay:)];

Comment: Good job. Post your solution as the answer once SO allows you to :-)

Comment: Yes ;) but I have to wait 8 hours after asking. I will do.

Comment: I want to integrate MPL to my app. But I have doubts about it. Does it allow me to transfer money from userA to userB? Does it supports all currencies? If not then does it at least notify the app that this transaction cannot be proceeded? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats the solution:

The problem was that I was not using the PayPal button. The app works properly when you insert   this:

```
[self addLabelWithText:@"Simple Payment" andButtonWithType:BUTTON_294x43 withAction:@selector(pay:)];
```